# ORMLite get single database column

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm trying to use this SQL command with Ormlite:

```
select address from receive
```

With this code:

```
List<Receivers> receiver_address = receiverDao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("address").query();
```

But the object returned is:

```
1 = {Receivers@830028192208} 
 address = {String@830028192264} "my new address"
 city = null
 email = null
 telephone = null
 mobile = null
 name_family = null
 national_code = null
 postal_code = null
 receiver_name = null
 id = 2
```

I need only `address` field in this query without `iterator` such as:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for( Receivers lst:receiver_address)
    list.add(lst.getAddress());
```

How to do this action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use RawRowMapper here:

```
List<String> addresses = receiverDao.queryRaw("select address from receive", new RawRowMapper<String>() {
       @Override
       public String mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) throws SQLException {
            return resultColumns[0];
       }
}).getResults();
```

Comment: thanks sir. can i use `.selectColumns` instead of `queryRaw` ?

Comment: I guess you can't do it without `queryRaw` but there is another way: `receiverDao.queryRaw(receiverDao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("address").prepareStatementString(), mapper);`

Comment: `RawRowMapper<String> mapper = new RawRowMapper<String>() {
       @Override
       public String mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) throws SQLException {
            return resultColumns[0];
       }
};`

Comment: The topic of selecting only a single column in a collection doesn't seem to come up much, but I discovered this answer after seeing an example of a custom rowMapper and having the same idea as was done here.  I feel this question and answer are underrated and maybe should not be limited to Android?

Comment: Yes I guess it's not only for Android, it works anywhere for ormlite.